# Using get_magic_quotes_gpc on PHP Version 5.2.14 or equivalent for PHP Version 6

Tags: php, magic-quotes, magic-quotes-gpc

Our site is using PHP Version 5.2.14

Lately our hoster probably changed magic-quote defenition, and I came up with the suggested solution [code bellow]

1. Is this solution OK for PHP Version 5.2.14 ?
2. What should I change when we upgrade to PHP version 6 ?

> ```
> // Code:
>
> function fHandleQuotes($s) {
>   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
>     return ($s);
>   return (addslashes($s));
> }
>
> . . .
> // Usage:
>
> . . . 
> $query = "UPDATE myTable SET myField = '" . fHandleQuotes($_POST['fieldName']) . "'";
> . . .
> ```

Comment: remove `return (addslashes($s));` and you will be o.k. And don't forget to handle data for the SQL query properly.

Comment: why should I remove the "return" ?

Comment: because addslashes has no use here. There should be database-specific action, not input data-specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 6 magic_quotes will be removed!
Now you can use this function.

```
if(  ( function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) || ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase')  ){
    foreach($_GET as $k => $v) $_GET[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    foreach($_COOKIE as $k => $v) $_COOKIE[$k] = stripslashes($v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will add the "function_exists()". But what would be the equivalent code in PHP 6 ?

Comment: In PHP 6 this code will not has the sense. Magic quotes will be removed. And they will be turned off.

Comment: It's a bit old, but... this code is incorrect. `magic_quotes_sybase` only overrides the `magic_quotes_gpc` escaping method when `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled. When `magic_quotes_gpc` is not enabled, `magic_quotes_sybase` has no effect in this respect. So, you should only be checking whether `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled, not whether `magic_quotes_sybase` is enabled. (If `magic_quotes_sybase` is enabled and `magic_quotes_gpc` is not then GET/POST/COOKIE data is not automatically escaped.)

Answer (score 1):

Read this and why you shouldn't use magic quotes:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Use one of the examples on that page and replace `stripslashes` with `addslashes`. But yes, your solution probably works. Though it would be faster and less intrusive to just use `$_GET = array_map("addslashes", $_GET);` once at startup. Even better would be to use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `addslashes` thereon. (But your database connection must already be established for this to work.)

Also I'd like to spamrecommend you this: http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/wiki/input/ - because it allows you to progressively rewrite your application to use `$_GET->q["fieldName"]` for (not so secure) magic quoted fields, or simply `$_POST->sql["fieldName"]` for (more secure) encoded fields.
You can even use `$_REQUEST->sql->always()` to enable the filter per default for all normal `$_REQUEST["fieldName"]` accesses. Though that might be overkill for some applications.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yes, but not quite. It doesn't prevent to use the dumbest possible filter. But it *eases* using a context specific and more appropriate filter.