# MySql is not working after installing AppServ of Windows 2008 Server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, appserver

I have installed AppServ 2.6.0 on Windows 2008 R2 but when I go to localhost/phpinfo.php I don't see mysql in there. I see "mysqlnd" I don't know what this is but it is there.

Moreover, Where i go to localhost/phpmyadmin I get an error in red

```
phpMyAdmin - Error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in C:\AppServ\www\phpMyAdmin\error.php on line 63
```

Please note that I have installed Innodb during the installation of AppServ 2.6.0.

What is wrong with this? why MySQL is not working? I have been working on this for couple of days so I aprechiate any help

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [Using get_magic_quotes_gpc on PHP Version 5.2.14 or equivalent for PHP Version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077543/using-get-magic-quotes-gpc-on-php-version-5-2-14-or-equivalent-for-php-version-6)

`get_magic_quotes_gpc` has been completely removed in PHP 6.

It has been deprecated since PHP 5.4 according to this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

As for MySQL, I'm not too familiar with AppServ, but do you need to enable the mysql modules in the php.ini?  Also, can you connect to mysql from the command line tool?

Comment: I have installed AppServ many time and it always worked exept when i am trying to install it on Windows Server 2008. I think the issue is port 3306. I am not sure if it is open or not. and how is the proper way to open it.

Comment: I did this to open port # 3306  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MySQL Server" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=3306

Comment: Is there a reason you're using 2.6.0? It's based on MySQL/PHP6 alpha/dev versions (from 2008?!).  It could be problematic because of that.

Comment: The reason why I used 2.6 is because POD mysql. I had problems with the older one so because it has a newer php version